# problem in implementing functionality in rating bar in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to implement custom rating bar in android.I am having problem.the problem i have discussed below

There is a Rating Bar.When u click on Play Movie Button.It will show you the total Number Of rating Bars = 5 .Now u quit the application.Now suppose u click at any rating bar say 3th ,  By Clicking on Play Video Button It will show 3+5/2. = 4.

My Java File is [pastebin.com/iC3rh7xm](http://pastebin.com/iC3rh7xm)

My Xml File is [pastebin.com/aWVB4CLU](http://pastebin.com/aWVB4CLU)

Can anyone help me....

Thanks in advance
tushar

Comment: I don’t understand. Do you mean that when there should be no vote, there is instead a 5 vote?

Comment: @guillaume,,,,what u mean by???u didnot understand the problem?

Comment: You question is confusing , I am not sure what the problem is?

Comment: Put your code here and explain clear what is your problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement I think you want it like this

```
total = rate.getNumStars();

    rate.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {

            rate_selected = (int)ratingBar.getRating();
        }
    });


  SaveRating.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(mainAct.this, "Rating Saved SuccessFully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println((total+rate_selected)/2);
        }
      });
```